# Change passwords of many schemas under different databases without DBA privileges?

Tags: oracle, plsql, sqlplus

We have many schemas under different databases. I do not have DBA privileges. I do have privileges to log-on to schemas and to change password. We do this password change ones in six months. Currently it's a manual and time consuming process. i.e. log-on to every schema under database/s and change password using "password" command. When I do password changes I have two files - current password and new password.

I log-on to each schema@database and issue following command –

```
alter user schema_name  identified by new_password  replace  old_password;
```

Remember I don’t have DBA privileges; I can only log-on to schemas using username and password.

I thought about creating shell script and using “expect” from shell script. Though first trying to find out whether there is any easier approach. I am wondering is there a simple way of doing this either from SQL*Plus or from PL/SQL?

Comment: Get the person with DBA privileges to either perform this task or to give you the necessary privileges. It's their job and forcing other people to do it without the necessary privileges is ridiculous. Yes, you could do something in code, a scripting language would probably be easiest rather than PL/SQL, but why would you want to go to all that effort when there's a much simpler solution?

Comment: You can use command `sqlplus schema/password@database`. Within SQLplus you can use `conn schema/password@database`. Maybe this helps.

Comment: Thanks Wernfried. DBA says it's responsibility of individual schema owners to change the passwords. I do have privileges to change password of schemas to which I can logon to. I have to use "alter user schema_name  identified by new_password  replace  old_password;" command. This is time consuming because I have to do this for 60+ schemas and each line put appropriate old and new password. Also the password for each schema is different hence it becomes very labor intensive work and have to do lots of cut and paste of old/new passwords.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems impossible to do it using PLSQL or SQL*Plus because using both of them, you can execute from a single schema only and since there is no DBA privilege, you cannot do it for all schemas, rather you will end up running script after logging into each schema.

You can write a shell script that reads the two files and for each line, it inserts following data into the third file,

```
sqlplus -s username_1/old_password_1@oracle_instance <<EOF
alter user username_1  identified by new_password1  replace  old_password_1;
exit
EOF

sqlplus -s username_2/old_password_2@oracle_instance <<EOF
alter user username_2  identified by new_password_2  replace  old_password_2;
exit
EOF
.
.
.

sqlplus -s username_n/old_password_n@oracle_instance <<EOF
alter user username_n  identified by new_password_n  replace  old_password_n;
exit
EOF
```

and so on

Once the third file is created, execute it after setting its permission to _rwxrwxrwx

Comment: You could stay in one session - started with `sqlplus /nolog` maybe - and issue a `connect` for each schema, followed by its `alter`. Same effect but would probably be a bit quicker than launching the executable 60 times.

Answer (score 1):

You need to script this.

Input: List of tnsalias, List of (schema_name, old password, new password).

Here is the script I use when I alter my account on multiple databases.

```
$ cat alterpassword.py 
"""Update oracle database passwords for user by typing the old and new password once.
"""

import cx_Oracle
import getpass

username = 'bjarte'

connect_strings = ['DB1.SUPERSITE.COM',
                   'DB2.SUPERSITE.COM',
                   'DB3.SUPERSITE.COM',
                   'DB4.SUPERSITE.COM',
                   'DB5.SUPERSITE.COM',
                   'DB6.SUPERSITE.COM']


def alter_password(username, old_password, new_password, tnsalias):


    connect_string = "%s/%s@%s" % (username, old_password, tnsalias)
    try:
        connection = cx_Oracle.connect(connect_string)
        try:
            cursor = connection.cursor()
            statement = "alter user %s identified by %s" % (username, new_password)
            cursor.execute(statement)
            return True
        except:
            return False
        else:
            cursor.close()
    except:
        return False
    else:    
        connection.close()    

if __name__ == '__main__':

    print "Type in old password"
    old_password = getpass.getpass()    
    print "Type in new password"
    new_password = getpass.getpass()    

    for tnsalias in connect_strings:
        success = alter_password(username, old_password, new_password, tnsalias)
        if success:
            print "password altered for user %s in database %s" % (username, tnsalias)
        else:
            print "password alternation failed for user %s in database %s" % (username, tnsalias)
```

You can adjust this script to read input from file and rewrite it in your favorite scripting language - bash, php, Perl, python, ruby or Powershell.

> Side note: Schema accounts are not application login-accounts

schema accounts should always be locked (no need for a password change).
When you request for ddl changes for a specific schema, the DBA can open up and give you a password. When done, lock the schema account again.

schema-accounts are *special*. They own objects and can do ddl like: `"drop objecttype objectname"`. You most likely don't want your applications to have these powerful privileges.